# Drawing linear gradient in a rect works on iOS 5.x but not 4.x

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-graphics

I have some code that I use to fill a view with a linear gradient, I've refactored this into a helper method. This draws fine on iOS 5.x but when I tried running on 4.3.5 I don't get anything. I've checked all the CG calls and they all are supported on 4.0 or older, it look so simplistic I can't see why it doesn't work on 4.x.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();    
CGColorRef startColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
CGColorRef endColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;    
CGRect paperRect = self.frame;
[GraphicsHelpers drawLinearGradientWithContext:context 
                                        inRect:paperRect 
                                    startColor:startColor 
                                      endColor:endColor];
}
```

Here is that method

```
+ (void)drawLinearGradientWithContext:(CGContextRef)context inRect:(CGRect)rect startColor:(CGColorRef)startColor endColor:(CGColorRef)endColor {

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGFloat locations[] = { 0.0, 1.0 };

NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(__bridge id)startColor, (__bridge id)endColor, nil];

CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, 
                                                    (__bridge CFArrayRef) colors, locations);

CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
CGContextClip(context);

CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);

CGGradientRelease(gradient);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

}

I found most of this code [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2033/core-graphics-101-lines-rectangles-and-gradients) and was working great until I started testing on older OS versions as I'm close to release.

Comment: For your paperRect, I would use `self.bounds` rather than `self.frame`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using supported API and you're getting different results from  one version of  the OS to another, file a bug report.

Comment: I'm just trying to make sure I'm not screwing something up before I go that route. Since most of the time when you think there is a API bug it really is your mistake.

Comment: Same code, different OS versions, different behavior, right?  That's a bug by definition.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, <strike>solved</strike> worked around it by creating the gradient using

```
CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents
```

.. instead of CGGradientCreateWithColors.

So, for a gradient from light gray to black you need to do the following:

```
CGFloat colors[8] = {
    0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f, 1.0f, // light gray
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f  // black
};

CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, colors, locations, 2);
```

This works in both iOS 4 and 5.

Answer (score 1):

I had to face the same problem as a tried to fill a view with a gradient. Finally I found out that the specific UIColor( redColor, whiteColor, etc) is incompatible with CGColors. 
Using ([UIColor whiteColor].CGColor) serves a CGColor which is not imcompatible or not supported in ios 4.3. For that reason I tried out to use [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor. This could be converted into CGColor space and finally I had a gradient in my view also with ios 4.3 and ios  5.x

Comment: Good to know. I ended up just dropping 4.x support for this app. I had filed a bug report and finally got a response from Apple that basically said yep its a bug. But we have moved on from 4.x so we won't fix. Which is understandable.